# How to remove the "knockout" from a Carlon PVC outdoor box?

Tags: wiring, junction-box

I purchased an outdoor GFI plug and box combo at Home Depot (Canada). The instructions I saw online talked about the inner box being metal and that you simply unscrewed the cap over the box hole you wanted to use for the cable - in this case the one on the back of the box because the wire comes out from the wall.

But that's not what's actually in the kit, it has a Carlon PVC box for the back, an "FS" I think? The holes into the box have a closure moulded right into them. They are STRONG. I looked for instructions but there's nothing on their web site and all I found elsewhere was how remove knock-outs from conventional metal boxes. There was an older post here about a PVC box that sounded like the plug was supposed to be rubbery and you pushed the cable right through it, that's not what I have.

So how the heck do you open these up?

Comment: How about a few pictures so we can see what you actually have.

Comment: A simple picture would show us what it is

Comment: It’s the first one here: https://carlonsales.com/switchboxes.php

Comment: Put an old screwdriver in the hole and whack it with a hammer. Then clean up the rough edges with something like a file.